# How to re-reproject coordinates that are coming from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, coordinates

I have a GeoJSON as follows:

> "type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":131445,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"2009BuildingsCOS.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[1308926.9929020153,171186.6402624961],[1308925.12256642,171176.955270945],[1308923.6956225059,171177.2343108883],[1308918.0723277144,171148.12967222783],[1308875.0080097103,171156.45018241392],[1308880.5196885085,171184.97062908477],[1308905.5063113617,171180.14093414505],[1308907.491334925,171190.41011768577],[1308926.9929020153,171186.6402624961]]]]}

Any suggestions about what coordinates I have?

Furthermore, I need to convert the coordinates to `WGS (also known as`EPSG 4326`). Ideally, I want to find a way to output the coordinates as GeoJSON directly from my GeoServer. The current GeoJSON with the unknown coordinates is here:

http://ec2-54-69-8-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/WRIA9/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WRIA9:2009BuildingsCOS&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json

Comment: Quite probably 3857, but also conceivably some UTM zone. It would help if you could tell us where in the world they are supposed to be, unless you don't know.

Comment: This is from the WRIA 9 data set, in Washington State, USA. My GeoServer is [here](http://ec2-54-69-8-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/web/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage), where this data set has the name `WRIA9:2009BuildingsCOS`

Comment: It was down when I tried, but Ian has already answered, you just add srsName=4326 and GeoServer will deal with the rest. Obviously, you have to tell GeoServer what the SRID is when you set the layer up, but I guess you didn't set it up?

Comment: For the record, the coordinates were `EPSG:2926`, found under the `layers` tab in GeoServer's admin panel, under the column `Native SRS`. Also, the units were in feet. I set up the GeoServer on Apache Tomcat, but I did not set up the layers. I assume that SRID sets the value for Native SRS? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have your WFS server reproject the data by adding the srsName parameter to your URL (i.e. http://ec2-54-69-8-151.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/geoserver/WRIA9/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=WRIA9:2009BuildingsCOS&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=epsg:4326).  Then your results will be what you want.

{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":131445,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"2009BuildingsCOS.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-122.17345722626978,47.461391938631515],[-122.17346410417348,47.46136530206787],[-122.17346989133587,47.46136599881724],[-122.17349057116665,47.461285952403514],[-122.17366521700366,47.46130670355382],[-122.1736449474416,47.46138514335701],[-122.17354361476038,47.46137309773591],[-122.17353631446726,47.46140134109307],[-122.17345722626978,47.461391938631515]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"PIN_2009":"1431600020","X":1308898.03,"Y":171171.02,"AREA_2009":1480.86865147,"BASE2005":0,"SHAPE_AREA":1480.86865147,"SHAPE_LEN":169.640704389}},{"type":"Feature","id":"2009BuildingsCOS.2","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[-122.17322302537582,47.46136614306344],[-122.17323071021336,47.46133690687326],[-122.17316810544474,47.4613293339197],[-122.17318915984316,47.46124934631671],[-122.17339162412138,47.46127385320279],[-122.17337036591307,47.461354598528146],[-122.17333949637063,47.46135086103058],[-122.173332003034,47.46137932986606],[-122.17322302537582,47.46136614306344]]]]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"PIN_2009":"1431600030","X":1308966.63,"Y":171158.45,"AREA_2009":1806.5779552,"BASE2005":0,"SHAPE_AREA":1806.5779552,"SHAPE_LEN":182.685636305}},